# ¿Cómo hago para generar un toogle con un botón y mover divs de lugar?

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy aprendiendo JS y lo que quiero es que cada vez que se presiona un botón, se mueva de un lado para el otro el bloque azul. Actualmente solo consigo que se mueva 1 vez. **¿En qué puedo estar fallando?**

*PD: La idea no es colocar clases con "float" sino mover directamente los elementos del DOM.*

Gracias :)

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let container = document.querySelector(".div-container");
let red = document.querySelector(".red");
let blue = document.querySelector(".blue");

function frente() {
  container.insertBefore(blue, container.firstElementChild);
};

function fondo() {
  container.insertAfter(blue, container.lastElementChild);
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.firstElementChild && red ? frente() : fondo();
});
```

```css
.div-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
}
.switch-container{
    display: flex;
}
.red{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgb(219, 124, 156);
}
.blue{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(99, 145, 212);
    height: 400px;
}
button{
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">Cambiar lado</button>
    </div>
    <div class="div-container">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- La función container.insertAfter no existe, lo que puedes hacer es obtener los dos elementos red y blue y remover uno del elemento contenedor(El primero) y después volverlo a agregar en el mismo contenedor:

```
container.removeChild(first_element);//Quitamo el primer elemento del nodo padre.
container.appendChild(first_elemento);//Lo agrega al final
```

2- ¿Porque no simplemente colocas una variable global que sea booleana que te diga en cual de los dos estas?.

```
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let container = document.querySelector(".div-container");
let red = document.querySelector(".red");
let blue = document.querySelector(".blue");
let in_fondo=true;
function fondo(){
    container.removeChild(red);
    container.appendChild(red);
    in_fondo=true;
}
function frente(){
    container.removeChild(blue);
    container.appendChild(blue);
    in_fondo=false;
}
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    in_fondo? frente() : fondo();
});
```

para que asi al llegar al onclick te sea mas fácil cambiarlas:

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    in_fondo? frente() : fondo();
});
```

Incluso puedes resumir mas la función:

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let colors=document.querySelector(".div-container div");//Obtiene el primer elemento div de la clase div-container.
    container.removeChild(colors);//Quitamos ese elemento del nodo.
    container.appendChild(colors);//Agregamos ese elemento al final.
});
```